# Where in object file does the code of function "main" starts?

Tags: c, assembly, memory, gdb, elf

I have an object file of a C program which prints hello world, just for the question.
I am trying to understand using readelf utility or gdb or hexedit(I can't figure which tool is a correct one) where in the file does the code of function "main" starts.

I know using readelf that symbol _start & main occurs and the address where it is mapped in a virtual memory. Moreover, I also know what the size of .text section and the of coruse where entry point specified, i.e the address which the same of text section.

The question is - Where in the file does the code of function "main" starts? I tought that is the entry point and the offset of the text section but how I understand it the sections data, bss, rodata should be ran before main and it appears after section text in readelf.

Also I tought we should sum the size all the lines till main in symbol table, but I am not sure at all if it is correct.

Additional question which follow up this one is if I want to replace main function with NOP instrcutres or plant one ret instruction in my object file. how can I know the offset where I can do it using hexedit.

Comment: You can just look at the section headers. Find which section contains the symbol's virtual address (should be `.text`) then subtract the start address of that section, finally add the file offset.

Comment: @Jester I am not sure I understand the formula. 
my addr. of .text section is the same as entry point, (for ex. 0x80482e0 and the offset is 0002e0 in section headers of .text section. Then you meant subtract it from entry point which the same, we get 0 and add offset, we get 2e0. Is it correct or I miss something?

Comment: Yes, that is just a happy little accident (TM) because your symbol is right at the beginning of a section so you can just use the offset directly.

Comment: Understood! one more little thing - how it is makes sense that it is the offset if it is before section .bss and .rodata and .data. the offset of these sections are come after main. But - as far I know program loads these sections before main. how it is makes sense?

Comment: It's irrelevant what order the sections are in memory, or in the file. All of the loadable sections (segments actually) are mapped before the code begins to execute at the given entry point. Historically you want the `.data` and `.bss` at the end of your memory layout so you can grow your heap using `brk`.

Comment: Use objdump with the disassemble option, and maybe other options, too.

Comment: The entry point is typically not `main`, but some runtime start, like `_start` or `__start`, usually found in `crt0.o`.  The operating system transfers control to the program in a primitive manner (ie. not using a call), and then `__start` builds the parameters for `main` and calls it.  This both gives `main` parameters as well as somewhere to return to, whereas `__start` must `exit` -- it cannot "return" to the operating system.

Comment: @ErikEidt Understood. Small confusion regarding entry point.
if entry point is _start then what the difference between symbol _start and segment text which has a same address? Do we have a case where entry point which is _start (and not main, when entry point is main so?) not equal to text section address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, let's go through it step by step.

Start with this C file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printit()
{
    puts("Hello world!");
}

int main(void)
{
    printit();
    return 0;
}
```

As the comments look like you are on x86, compile it as 32-bit non-PIE executable like this:

```
$ gcc -m32 -no-pie  -o test test.c
```

The `-m32` option is needed, because I am working at a x86-64 machine. As you already know, you can get the virtual memory address of main using readelf, objdump or nm, for example like this:

```
$ nm test | grep -w main
0804918d T main
```

Obviously, `804918d` can not be an offset in the file that is just 15 kB big. You need to find the mapping between *virtual memory addresses* and *file offsets*. In a typical ELF file, the mapping is included *twice*. Once in a detailed form for linkers (as object files are also ELF files) and debuggers, and a second time in a condensed form that is used by the kernel for loading programs. The detailed form is the list of sections, consisting of section headers, and you can view it like this (the output is shortened a bit, to make the answer more readable):

```
$ readelf --section-headers test
There are 29 section headers, starting at offset 0x3748:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
[...]
  [11] .init             PROGBITS        08049000 001000 000020 00  AX  0   0  4
  [12] .plt              PROGBITS        08049020 001020 000030 04  AX  0   0 16
  [13] .text             PROGBITS        08049050 001050 0001c1 00  AX  0   0 16
  [14] .fini             PROGBITS        08049214 001214 000014 00  AX  0   0  4
  [15] .rodata           PROGBITS        0804a000 002000 000015 00   A  0   0  4
[...]
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), I (info),
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
  C (compressed), x (unknown), o (OS specific), E (exclude),
  p (processor specific)
```

Here you find that the `.text` section starts at (virtual) address `08049050` and has a size of `1c1` bytes, so it ends at address `08049211`. The address of main, `804918d` is in this range, so you know `main` is a member of the text section. If you subtract the base of the text section from the address of main, you find that main is `13d` bytes into the text section. The section listing also contains the file offset where the data for the text section starts. It's `1050`, so the first byte of main is at offset `0x1050 + 0x13d == 0x118d`.

You can do the same calculation using program headers:

```
$ readelf --program-headers test
[...]
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  PHDR           0x000034 0x08048034 0x08048034 0x00160 0x00160 R   0x4
  INTERP         0x000194 0x08048194 0x08048194 0x00013 0x00013 R   0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux.so.2]
  LOAD           0x000000 0x08048000 0x08048000 0x002e8 0x002e8 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x001000 0x08049000 0x08049000 0x00228 0x00228 R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x002000 0x0804a000 0x0804a000 0x0019c 0x0019c R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x002f0c 0x0804bf0c 0x0804bf0c 0x00110 0x00114 RW  0x1000
[...]
```

The second load line tells you that the area `08049000` (VirtAddr) to `08049228` (VirtAddr + MemSiz) is readable and executable, and loaded from offset `1000` in the file. So again you can calculate that the address of main is `18d` bytes into this load area, so it has to reside at offset `0x118d` inside the executable. Let's test that:

```
$ ./test
Hello world!
$ echo -ne '\xc3' | dd of=test conv=notrunc bs=1 count=1 seek=$((0x118d))
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1 byte copied, 0.0116672 s, 0.1 kB/s
$ ./test
$
```

Overwriting the first byte of main with `0xc3`, the opcode for return (near) on x86, causes the program to not output anything anymore.

Comment: Understood. thank you! Alternately, I can put NOP instruction and not override ret. if the start address is 118d then we should put NOP till (118d + size of main function), before C3 opcode. is it correct?

Comment: You can't be sure that the last opcode of main is always the ret instruction. If there are if blocks the compiler deems unlikely to be executed, the compiler might place their code after the RET opcode. Of course, you can NOP out everything until the first C3 byte. It will work, even if the C3 was actually an operand or part of an address.

Comment: On the other hand, there doesn't even have to be a RET instruction in main at all. If the compiler can apply tail call optimization on all code paths, it will always jump out of main. Also if main calls functions that are known to not return, the compiler may stop compiling code past those calls.

Answer (score 2):

`_start` normally belongs to a module ( a `*.o` file) that is fixed (it is called differently on different systems, but a common name is `crt0.o` which is written in assembler.)  That fixed code prepares the stack (normally  the arguments and the environment are stored in the initial stack segment by the `execve(2)` system call) the mission of `crt0.s` is to prepare the initial C stack frame and call `main()`.  Once `main()` ends, it is responsible of getting the return value from main and calling all the `atexit()` handlers to finish calling the `_exit(2)` system call.

The linking of `crt0.o` is normally transparent due to the fact that you always call the compiler to do the linking itself, so you normally don't have to add `crt0.o` as the first object module, but the compiler knows (lately, all this stuff has grown considerably, since we depend on architecture and ABIs to pass parameters between functions)

If you execute the compiler with the `-v` option, you'll get the exact command line it uses to call the linker and you'll get the secrets of the final memory map your program has on its first stages.